# FileUpload widget gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I'm working on an application and I use gwt. I need to upload files (images) and for that purpose I use the FileUpload widget. When the user hasn't upload file the text in that widget is "No selected file", and I want to change that, but I dont know how to access that part of the widget.

Comment: Retagging it as I couldn't find any `FileUpload` widget in SmartGWT library.

Comment: Yeah RAS you are right. It is in import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui. Thank you for your edit :)

Comment: Like I can notice, the widget is consisting of one button named Browse and one label "No selected file", and I want to access the label and change the content.

Answer (score 2):

FileUpload is rendered as a `<input type=file>` so you are going to see the default browser implementation for that widget. In fact if you use a different browser the text would be a different one or none.

Because of security reasons, most browser vendors have refused to offer ways to style file-input, so you have to use some hack to replace it by a customized button/div. etc. Hence there is no so much you can do to change that text.

I would recommend to use [gwtupload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload), its [DecoratedFileUpload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/CustomWidgets) widget comes with some tweaks to hide the default upload button and show a customized one to open the browse dialog, take a look to its [examples](http://gwtupload.alcala.org).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following and it's working fine in Mozilla FireFox 25.0.

In your css file define a new style:

```
.myfile {
  color: transparent;
}
```

Now apply this style to your FileUpload widget as follows:

```
fileUpload.setStyleName("myfile");
```

Hope it helps you.